How to fix PowerBI formula - DAX has red line with no error code
I am trying to run some analysis, and typed a formula to attempt to do so, but the DAX is giving me the redline error, with no error message.
I have no idea why this formula wont run, so any suggestions would be appreciated. Here is a screenshot:

Tried recreating the formula, modifying, etc, but nothing would push it through. Any help would be super appreciated.
Also a copy of the formula:
Customer Retention % = 
VAR CurrentMonthAfter = SELECTEDVALUE('Months After'[Value])
VAR CurrentFirstOrderMonth = SELECTEDVALUE('JOD REPORTS'[First Order Date (EOM)])
Return
DIVIDE(
    CALCULATE(
        DISTINCTCOUNT('JOD REPORTS'[Customer Number]),
        FILTER(
            'JOD REPORTS',
            EOMONTH('JOD REPORTS'[Order Date],0) = EOMONTH(CurrentFirstOrderMonth,CurrentMonthAfter)
        )
    ),
    DISTINCTCOUNT('JOD REPORTS'[Customer Number])
)


Pass your cursor on the red rectangle in the right bottom side

@AmiraBedhiafi No dialogue box pops up when I hover the red. It only shows up when I am on the very outside of the textbook, and doesnt give any prompts, error codes, popups, etc

I have a doubt with your numerator have you tried using variables?

I have a doubt with your numerator so you may need to use variables to make your code easier to read and debug :
Customer Retention % = 
VAR CurrentMonthAfter = SELECTEDVALUE('Months After'[Value])
VAR CurrentFirstOrderMonth = SELECTEDVALUE('JOD REPORTS'[First Order Date (EOM)])
VAR CurrentEOMonth = EOMONTH(CurrentFirstOrderMonth, CurrentMonthAfter)

VAR DistinctCustomerCount =
    CALCULATE(
        DISTINCTCOUNT('JOD REPORTS'[Customer Number]),
        FILTER(
            'JOD REPORTS',
            EOMONTH('JOD REPORTS'[Order Date], 0) = CurrentEOMonth
        )
    )

VAR TotalDistinctCustomerCount = DISTINCTCOUNT('JOD REPORTS'[Customer Number])

RETURN
DIVIDE(DistinctCustomerCount, TotalDistinctCustomerCount)

